# drawtriangles function in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I need to do some image transformation in JavaScript.
[image]
[image]
Looking for an alternative of **AS3  drawtriangles** function. I used **IvanK Lib**, it's very powerful but works over WebGL. Need a way to do it only with canvas.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say "only with canvas", do you mean only with the canvas's 2D context?

Your text examples are non-parallel transforms.  You can't do non-parallel transforms in 2D context.

I think I understand from your question that you don't want to use 3D context--as opposed to not wanting to use IvanKLib.  You **can** do your text transforms in 3D context without IvanKLib.  Canvas's 3D context is WebGL and works in Chrome and Firefox.

Using 2D context, the closest you can get is to manipulate pixels.  Here's a good post on triangular distorting of images at the pixel level: http://codeslashslashcomment.com/2012/12/12/dynamic-image-distortion-html5-canvas/

Comment: Yes, using 2D context. That's is what I need. Thanks a lot!